# MySQL Syntax Error when using JSON array as value

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

My Table:

- customer_id INT (PRIMARY KEY)
- purchased_products JSON
- refunded_products = JSON

Expected values

- 12345
- ["32","33","34"]
- ["31","38","39"]

The following SQL works as expected. Great!

```
 -- Insert a new row into the purchased products table
INSERT INTO dc_purchased_products (
    user_id, -- INT
    purchased_products -- JSON
)

-- 1) The user ID (primary key)
-- 2) Formatted json array with the first purchased product ID
VALUES ( 12345, '["36"]' )

-- If the user id already exists, append the existing array with the product ID
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 

-- JSON_ARRAY_INSERT(existing purchases array, index, product_id)
purchased_products = JSON_ARRAY_INSERT(purchased_products, '$[0]', "36")
```

However, my PDO satements in my application arent so good.

```
$item = [
  'statement' => "INSERT INTO purchased_products 
                        (customer_id, purchased_products) 
                  VALUES(:customer_id, [:purchased_products]) 
                    ON DUPLICATE KEY 
                    UPDATE purchased_products = JSON_ARRAY_INSERT(purchased_products, '$[0]',:purchased_products)",
  'data' => [
    ['customer_id' => 12345, 'purchased_products' => '"36"'],
    ['customer_id' => 12345, 'purchased_products' => '"37"']
  ]
]
```

My Connection

```
$this->connection = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database", $u, $p, [
  PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY                => $ck,
  PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT               => $cc,
  PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA                 => $sc,
  PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => false,
]);

$this->connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


$statement = $this->connection->prepare($item['statement']);
foreach ($item['data'] as $rowData) {

    foreach ($rowData as $key => $param) {
        $statement->bindValue(':' . $key, $param);
    }

    try {
        $success = $statement->execute();
    }

    catch (PDOException $e) {
        pre($e->getMessage());        
    }

}
```

Error message

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '['3784835']) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE purchased_products = JSON_ARRAY_INSERT(purc' at line 1

Comment: Your query has 3 parameters but you only pass 2, so you have to pass the value for `purchased_products` twice once if use in the INSERT and once for use in the UPDATE

Comment: But my query only has two params. customer_id and purchased_products.

Comment: Can you show us your connection parameter (not the password) but all the others

Comment: I want to see what you set `ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` to

Comment: @RiggsFolly I had suspected this was something to do with the JSON syntax in the initial INSERT vs the UPDATE

Comment: Surely it is not related to the problem, but why these table names are different? `INSERT INTO dc_purchased_products (` in SQL string, and `INSERT INTO purchased_products ` in PDO string?

Comment: Maybe you should add the missing `'` here: `VALUES(:customer_id, [:purchased_products])` to look like the example provided in SQL:  `VALUES ( 12345, '["36"]' )`.  It has sense because the error starts in that value: `near '['3784835']) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE purchased_products = JSON_ARRAY_INSERT(purc' at line 1`.  So I bet to try to use them like this: `VALUES(:customer_id, '[:purchased_products]')` and test again, or if not allowed then change this: `'purchased_products' => '"36"'` by this `'purchased_products' => '["36"]'` and remove the `[ ]` in the `[:purchased_products]`

Comment: @masterguru sorry  I was trying to keep the prefix "dc" out of the question. You are right though, the table is called dc_purchased_products.

Comment: @masterguru I'll try

Comment: If you enable debugging, capture the Query (If using variables) then run this query directly into your database. Play around with the query until you can see where it is wrong, then update your PHP statement. Enabling and using debugging will save you many hours of headaches

Comment: @masterguru if I add the brakcets around the initial purchased_products element in the array, it will add those brackets to both INSERT and UPDATE. If you add them to update it will add a whole new array instead of appending the existing one. Also I think that first single quote is part of the error message itself.

Comment: My previous comment was a bit mess, but could you try this?  Change `VALUES(:customer_id, [:purchased_products])`by `VALUES(:customer_id, :purchased_products)` and then, in the data array, set the purchased_products values like this: `'purchased_products' => '["36"]'` and `'purchased_products' => '["37"]'` and tell the result, please... or... ops... wait... it only will run when INSERT, but not when UPDATE... now I see the problem, sorry

Comment: I have answered this question and improved the explanation. Take a look and check it please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should fix the problem:

```
$item = [
  'statement' => "INSERT INTO purchased_products 
                        (customer_id, purchased_products) 
                  VALUES(:customer_id, :purchased_products) 
                    ON DUPLICATE KEY 
                    UPDATE purchased_products = JSON_ARRAY_INSERT(purchased_products, '$[0]',:purchased_products_json)",
  'data' => [
    ['customer_id' => 12345, 'purchased_products' => '["36"]', 'purchased_products_json' => '36'],
    ['customer_id' => 12345, 'purchased_products' => '["37"]', 'purchased_products_json' => '37'],
  ]
];
```

### Explanation of changes:

**Removed `[` and `]`** in `VALUES(:customer_id, [:purchased_products])`

Now it looks like this:

```
VALUES(:customer_id, :purchased_products)
```

This change will avoid the error during the `execute()`.

**New param in JSON_ARRAY_INSERT:  *purchased_products_json***

Now it looks like this:

```
JSON_ARRAY_INSERT(purchased_products, '$[0]',:purchased_products_json)
```

To avoid the error now we need two params with small diferences. One for the INSERT (`purchased_products`) and other for the UPDATE (`purchased_produtcs_json`) because they have different formats despite same values.

**In `data` array, changed `'purchased_products' => '"36"'`**

Now it looks like this:

```
'purchased_products' => '["36"]'
```

because we will use it during INSERT stament, and we need to set it as new JSON array value with correct format and because we already removed the `[` and `]` in the previous INSERT statement.

**In `data` array, added new param: `'purchased_products_json'`**

In order to UPDATE the field, the value format should be different, so we need this new param. It looks like this:

```
'purchased_products_json' => '36'
```

avoiding the use of `[` and `]`. You can see some information about JSON_ARRAY_INSERT in [mariadb documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_array_insert/)

Comment: that you so much for your efforts and I can see what your changes mean, it makes sense. Unfortunately I dont return to the office until Monday. However this will be the first thing I do and I will defo complete the question / answer etc.

Comment: No hurry. Thanks. Be sure to verify it first because I am not able to reproduce it (well, I can, but too much work :-))

Comment: yup that nailed it. You were right to add the extra param for the update. Great work, thanks again.